# Using GoogleMaps with JXMapKit

Tags: google-maps, jxmapviewer

I have been searching on the web to see if I can use GoogleMaps with the JXMapViewer.
According to [this](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/joshy/archive/2006/10/nasa_maps_in_yo.html), it is illegal, but the article is more than three years old.
Could anyone be kind enough to tell me if I can use GoogleMaps with the JXMap viewer? I know that Google has recently allowed desktop applications to use their static maps provided that the application is freely accessible to people on some website.

If this can be done, I would appreciate some pointer to where I could start looking so that I can use Google Maps, I tried messing around with [this](http://hochreiter.wordpress.com/2008/06/30/swinglabs-jmapkit-and-google-maps/) but to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I have managed to show a map in my JXMapKit. The only problem is that I am getting the image as a tiled image, whilst I only need one. Any help on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the JXMapViewer will never be able to use GoogleMaps since Google decided to not make their Tile Servers available to the general public, as shown [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1396).